# ODBC Refresh Connection String Error in VBA / Run Time Error 1004

Tags: vba, connection, odbc

I am having troubles with a VBA macro that used to run great before but now it suddenly stop working for one of my files. The macro objective is to update the ODBC Query connection string based on different parameters inputted on several cells.

I used the debug function to find the problem. It looks like the problem originates at the "With" statement. The error windows shows: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Attached you will find the code.

```
Sub updateCnnStr()
'Variables for workbook and connection
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim odbc As WorkbookConnection


'Set workbook variable as ThisWorkbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

'For each connection string, change DSN, Description, and Database
For Each odbc In wb.Connections



**With odbc.ODBCConnection**
.Connection = _
"ODBC;DSN=" & wb.Worksheets(1).Range("DSN") & ";Description=" & wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Description") & ";UID=lopezro2;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=US-CCR1-L08;DATABASE=" & wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Database")

End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you do not need the with-statement. Why don't you write
odbc.ODBCConnection.Connection = ...?

Due to my experience with VBA you should use Option Explicit in the first line of every module an then try to compile the code, if you did not so far. Sometimes errors are at other locations...

You should also build your connection-string first in a string-variable and then assign it to .connection. So you can see, if the problem comes from the arguments of the string or the fault is in the connection-string.